# How do i load something like cheerio in html using an external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

So I am working on my first project and I cant seem to load a scraper js file since the html says that 'require' is not defined.

I have heard about requirejs, but its a bit hard for me to understand.

So this is my javascript file:

```
const malScraper = require('mal-scraper');

// more code ...

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = currentSeason;
```

and then in index.html i want it to load the scraped results in a paragraph
like this

```
<p id='output'>Here: </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require is not implemented in the browser natively, you'll need a polyfill (it's a dependency that reproduces its behavior).

It's the purpose of Require.js, Browserify, and other packages.

Here's a sample code with Browserify:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

   <!-- Your HTML Stuff -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./browserify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    const malscraper = require('./mal-scraper'); // The path to the dependency

    malscraper(): // And now you can use it
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll be sure to try it out.